# How can I access the raw bytes of a CD using Java?

Tags: java, windows, cd-rom

Not sure if this is possible, but can I access the raw bytes of a compact disc using Java? If so could you provide a sample of code please? I am using Windows and don't mind platform specific code.

Comment: OMG how is this not a real question?  What is wrong with you people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do it in Java.  You will have to write native C code using Windows API (start with CreateFile as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138434)) and then call it using [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) from Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the operating system with a platform specific  API - under Linux there is most likely a /dev file for this,